# RandomizedPCA memory usage

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

How to determine max memory peak usage used by [RandomizedPCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.RandomizedPCA.html)?
Also may be there is some analytical formula for score from above for RandomizedPCA?

Answer (score 1):

Use [memory_profiler](https://github.com/fabianp/memory_profiler) by Fabian Pedregosa (former release manager for scikit-learn). This is the tool the sklearn developers themselves use to profile the library.

Comment: May be there is some analytical formula for score from above for RandomizedPCA?

Comment: I don't have an analytical formula at hand be you can use `memory_profiler` for input data various shapes `(n_samples, n_features)` and `n_components` and work it out yourself :)

Comment: FYI the main code doing the processing is pretty simple: it mostly in [randomized_svd](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/extmath.py#L209) and the [randomized_range_finder](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/extmath.py#L162) functions.

Comment: @ogrisel "simple" isn't really the word with all those matrix multiplications :) In any case, the complexity depends on whether `copy=True`. When that's `False`, and `n_components` < `n_features` as the algorithm is intended, I believe it's O(`n_samples` × `n_components` + `n_features` × `n_components`), i.e. the output size.